# Selenium+chromedriver failing on DOM mutation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to Selenium, and I'm having issues with a login test case when using `ChromeDriver`. For this webpage, we have a DOM mutation that hides the login form initially.

If I'm using `FirefoxDriver` or `SafariDriver`, this test case works perfectly fine. However, it has issues with `ChromeDriver`. I've tested other sites with `ChromeDriver`, and it works, so I don't believe it's an issue with my `ChromeDriver` setup.

Initially, I tried to write this testcase by having the driver wait until the login element was visible:

```
WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("form.loginForm")));
```

The test case errors out with

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: bad inspector
>   message.

I've tried downgrading to Selenium 2.45 to see if the results differ. They don't.

I even tried `Thread.sleep()`, and then `driver.findElement()`, and I still get the same error. Any kind of element finding, whether by id, cssSelector, xpath, and className, will yield the same error.

After banging my head on this for 2 days, I decide to consult the wonderful crowd here at StackOverflow for suggestions. The versions of my Chrome, ChromeDriver, and Selenium are listed below. Thank you!

```
Chrome: Version 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit)
Chromedriver: 2.16
Seleium: tried 2.45.0 & 2.46.0
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide the url of the website.

Comment: I have the same problem, any solution yet?